# Call a method after a callback and an event

Tags: javascript, callback, dojo, dijit.form, arcgis-js-api

I have a module with four functions that call one after the other. I am trying to follow the Revealing Module Pattern. One of the functions is public, the remaining are private. It goes like this:

1. `publicMethod` is called from another module
2. `queryNames` is called from `publicMethod`
3. `execute(parameters, callback?, errback?)` is called from `queryNames`
4. `addNamesList` is called as the `callback?` argument of `execute`
5. Several `dijit/form/CheckBox`'s are created and the method `querySegments` is triggered `onChange`
6. `querySegments` needs to call a method of an object created in `publicMethod`.

The problem is in step 6, I can't reach the object created in step 1.

I have tried to use [dojo hitch](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-hitch) to define the `callback?` argument in step 3, but I can't get it to work. I tried putting `this` in its first argument, but even then I can't reach the required scope to call `addNamesList`.

Here is some code to demonstrate this issue.

```
define([
  'dojo/dom',
  'dijit/form/CheckBox',
  'esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer',
  'esri/tasks/query',
  'esri/tasks/QueryTask',
  'dojo/_base/lang'
],
  function (
    dom,
    CheckBox,
    ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,
    Query, QueryTask,
    lang
  ) {
    // ***************
    // private methods
    // ***************

    // fetch names and call addNamesList to put the list in place
    var queryNames = function (map, mapLayer) {
      // new QueryTask(url, options?)
      var queryTask = new QueryTask("url")
      var query = new Query()
      // execute(parameters, callback?, errback?)
      // this callback passes an argument called featureSet
      queryTask.execute(query, lang.hitch(map, "addNamesList", mapLayer), function(error) {console.log(error)})
    }  

    // callback function of queryNames
    var addNamesList = function (mapLayer, featureSet) {
      console.log('addOplist')
      var namesCount = featureSet.features.length
      for (var i = 0; i <namesCount; i++) {
        // work
        var cbox = new CheckBox({
          id: "cbox_" + i,
          value: featureSet.features[i].attributes["someID"],
          checked: false,
          onChange: function (evt) {
            querySegments(this.value, mapLayer)
          }
        })
        cbox.placeAt("someDiv" + i, "first")
      }
    }

    // triggered by the checkbox event
    var querySegments = function (name, mapLayer) {
        // build the query
        var queryStatement = "someID = " + name
        var layerDefinitions = [queryStatement]
        // call a method of mapLayer
        mapLayer.setLayerDefinitions(layerDefinitions)
    }

    // **************
    // public methods
    // **************
    var publicMethod = function (map) {
      var mapLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer('restURL')
      map.addLayer(mapServiceLayer)
      queryNames(map, mapLayer)
      return mapLayer
    }

    return {
      publicMethod: publicMethod
    }
  }
)
```

You can see a more detailed explanation and a working example on [this other (and more broad) question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113563/91955) that I have put on Code Review.

I am new to JavaScript and I guess I still have a lot of issues with scoping, closures and callbacks.

I will deeply appreciate any input, including how to improve this question.

### Edit

With this current implementation (with dojo hitch), no error is thrown. The method `addNamesList` is not called (nor `errback`, which I also don't understand why). I think this is because `addNamesList` is not on `map`'s (hitch first argument) namespace. I tried to put `this` instead, but it makes no difference.

Before I decided to use hitch, the code looked like this:

```
var queryNames = function (map, mapLayer) {
  ...
  queryTask.execute(query, addNamesList)
}

var addNamesList = function (featureSet) {
  ...
    ...
      ...
        querySegments(this.value, mapLayer)
}
```

but then I couldn't reach `mapLayer` inside the method triggered by the check box event. It would throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: mapLayer is not defined`. That is why I tried to use hitch.

Comment: Does it throw any errors? I'm not quite into dojo, but it appears yo me that you've kinda messed with callbacks :)

Comment: @AlexanderM. thank you for your comment and answer. As it is right now, it does not throw any errors. I've edited my question to add some more info. You're right, I am pretty messed up with callbacks. I wish there were a Zen of JavaScript, as there is for [Python](http://www.thezenofpython.com).

Comment: @ilied Well, in fact it's just a matter of getting used to the asynchronous way of thinking.

Comment: If you google for *callback hell*, you'll probably find some weirder stuff, but the languae is constantly evolving and now we have generators+promises and ES7's async/await in Babel, so everything's OK :)

Comment: @Alexander M. Thanks. I've read about _callback hell_, I guess that's where I'm going to. I will try to (understand and) apply your suggestion/answer.

Comment: good luck with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous, so pretty much data coming from db, http requests or whatever is returned via **callbacks**. Here's what happens in your code:

- public method calls queryNames
- queryNames call `addNamesList` of `map` asynchronously and returns nothing
- public method takes back control, meanwhile some stuff is going on with the `addNamesList`
- `mapLayer` is returned untouched while some stuff is still going on in the background

So, to avoid this, you should return data from public method via callback, so you pass `callback` as the second parameter to the public method, then to the querySegments. Then, in the success callback of `query`, when you finally get the result ready, you do:

```
callback(mapLayer);
```

So, everything you should do is to pass this `callback` as deep as needed to the place where you have your `mapLayer` ready (so you've done with it everything you wanted), and then do a `callback(mapLayer);`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) would probably explain better.

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderM. for taking the time to read and answer this question. I think I understood what you've suggested, I can see how it would work, and for that reason I am accepting your answer. However, meanwhile, I tried using `lang.partial` instead of `lang.hitch` and it worked. I didn't have to define another callback function. Probably this is not the best approach, but is working for now... thanks.